# Adding views to ConstraintLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but this seems so difficult to achieve through code.

What I am trying to achieve is to extend the `ConstraintLayout` and add two views to it. I have the following code:

```
class TestLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val ids = mutableListOf<Int>()

    init {
        addTextView()
        addTextView()

        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clone(this)

        set.connect(ids[0], ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 200)
        set.connect(ids[1], ConstraintSet.TOP, ids[0], ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)

        set.applyTo(this)
    }

    private fun addTextView() {
        val view = TextView(context)

        addView(view, LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))

        view.id = View.generateViewId()
        view.text = view.id.toString()

        ids.add(view.id)
    }
}
```

When running this code the first view is properly displayed, but the second one is in the top left corner (as if there are no constraints on it).

What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add at least *one horizontal* & *one vertical* constraint to view adding in **`ConstraintLayout`**,

Here, it's not satisfied in init constructor:

```
set.connect(ids[0], ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 200) // no vertical constraint (Top/Bottom), so view will add at 0 position of y axis
set.connect(ids[1], ConstraintSet.TOP, ids[0], ConstraintSet.BOTTOM) // No horizontal constraint so that view 2 will jump to position (0,0)
```

Do like this:

```
// Add constraints for View 1
set.connect(ids[0], ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 200)
set.connect(ids[0], ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 20) // Add top constraint to your view 1
set.connect(ids[0], ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 200) // Optional if you want symmetry of view 1 in layout

// Add constraints for view 2
set.connect(ids[1], ConstraintSet.TOP, ids[0], ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
set.connect(ids[1], ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 200) // Add start constraint to view 2
set.connect(ids[1], ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 200) // Optional if you want symmetry of view 2 in layout
```

Read it from [**ConstraintLayout**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) & [**ConstraintSet**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet).